# If $y \in f(E)'$ with $E \subseteq X$ dense then $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in X$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

> Let $f$ be continuous function on $X$ and let $E$ be a dense subset of $X$. Then if $y \in f(E)'$, i.e. if $y$ is limit point of $f(E)$, show that there exists $x \in X$ such that $y = f(x)$.

I can't solve this problem.
Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to the last question and is also false.  Let $f:(0,1)\rightarrow [0,1]$ be defined by $f(x) = x$.  Let $E = (0,1)$.  Every topological space is dense in itself, so $E$ is a dense subset of $X = (0,1)$.  $1$ is a limit point of $f(E) = (0,1)\subset [0,1]$, but there is no $x\in X =  (0,1)$ so that $x= f(x) = 1$.

edit: This appears to be part of a proof attempt at question 4.4 of Rudin's analysis book.  The above example should still show that the claim you are trying to prove is not correct.  To be clear, $X = (0,1)$ and $Y = [0,1]$.  These are metric spaces with the metric $d(x,y) = |x - y|$.  $f(x) = x$ is a continuous function between these metric spaces.

In this problem, you are trying to show that $f(E)$ is a dense subset of $f(X)$.  This is not the same as showing that $\overline{f(E)} = f(X)$.

You want to prove that if $y$ is in $f(X)$, then $y$ is a limit point of the set $f(E)$.  You don't want to show that every limit point of $f(E)$ is a point in $f(X)$.

In symbols, you want to show $f(E)\subset f(X) \subset \overline{f(E)}$, not $f(X) = \overline{f(E)}$.

Comment: This is questions is part of Rudin Principal of mathematical analysis.Sir I don't know about topology that why I don't get your answer .sorry for that.but I thought hard on my previous solution form last 2 days .but I don't able to get.

Comment: Thanks a lots Sir.i don't have this knowledge. I had confusion with definition of dense set

Comment: What was the last question, @user585541 ?